# Ruby terminal code not working

Tags: ruby

When I run this Ruby code on the Terminal, it won't display "it works" on the console. What is wrong with this code?

```
f = File.open("hello.txt", 'w')
f.puts "Hello World"

text = IO.read("hello.txt")

if text == "Hello World"
  puts "it works"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things to note.

1) when you write to a file using `File`, it buffers the data for efficiency (rather than repeatedly writing to the filesystem) so you'll want to `flush` the handle to make sure to actually write to it with any buffered data.  You can do this explicitly by invoking `flush` or implicitly by closing the handle.

2) when you `gets` from user input or read from the filesystem, it's usually a good idea to `strip` any trailing whitespace characters.  Your equality evaluation will fail without: `text.strip == "Hello World"`

3) rather than opening two handles to the same file (via `File` and `IO`), you could open a single read/write stream by switching from `w` to `w+`.  Then you could rewind to the correct position.

Here's how that approach might look:

```
f = File.new("hello.txt", 'w+')
f.puts "Hello World"
f.rewind
text = f.read.strip
puts "It works" if text == "Hello World"
```

Comment: What if I want to do this  to read the file                                                                                   f = File.open("text.txt", 'r')
f.rewind
text = f.read.strip

if text == "Hello"
  puts "It works"
end

Answer (score 1):

You must close the stream to save data inside.

```
f = File.open("hello.txt", "w"){|file| file << "Hello World"}

text = IO.read(f.path)

if text == "Hello World"
  puts "it works"
end
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You are missing f.close:

```
f = File.open("hello.txt", 'w') 
f.puts "Hello World"
f.close
text = IO.read("hello.txt")
puts "it works"  if text == "Hello World"
```